# Does MVC SelectListItem not Implement Equals?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, equality

Busy writing a unit test for a controller that produces a view-model that includes a list of options as IEnumerable < SelectListItem >. I tried checking that the expected list contains all the ones in the view-model and vice-versa. To my surprise this is always false. So I created the following test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanEqual()
{
  var x = new SelectListItem {Selected = false, Text = "A", Value = "A"};
  var y = new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "A", Value = "A" };
  Assert.AreEqual(x, y); 
}
```

The assertion always fails but the two are equal. Does SelectListItem really not implement Equals or am I just missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to Shark's answer... As for what to do about it, other than implementing `IEquatable<T>` on a derived class (and if you do that, you really should override the non-generic `Equals()` too - and if you do *that*, you really should override `GetHashCode()`)... Anyway... other than doing that, you could:

1. Create a helper method in your test project to do the value comparison (it's possible to write a general purpose one using Reflection that would work for most simple classes), or
2. Make a helper class implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>` for each of the types you need to compare.

Neither will allow you to use `Assert.AreEqual()`, but in general, I'm not in favor of adding code to your objects just to allow testing - prefer keeping it in the test project. Plus, with these approaches, you won't "need" to implement `GetHashCode()` etc.

Answer (score 2):

That's because by default, it is testing for the same reference.  In this case, you have two instances of the object, therefore they aren't "equal".

If you want to alter that behavior, you just need to implement the `IEquatable<T>` interface, and you can redefine what `Equals()` will return.  For instance:

```
public bool Equals(YourClass other)
{
    return (this.Value == other.Value);
}
```

For a good reference on `Object.Equals()`, please see [this MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx).  Equality for reference types is based on their reference.  I.e. if they don't reference the same object then `Equals()` will return `false`.

Comment: Which is to say, GrantVS is "right" - SelectListItem really does not implement its own Equals. In fact, the implementation of SelectListItem is nothing but three auto-implemented properties. Just adding that here, since Shark's answer is (as always) perfect already.

Comment: So SelectListItem's provided Equals method looks at references (would have expected the == operator to do that) and I have to extend it to be able to compare two instances?

Comment: @GrantVS: Added an answer about some of the alternatives. But yes, the `==` will usually compare identity for reference types, even when `Equals()` is overridden. But in this case, both compare identity, because they're both inherited straight from `Object`.